# Disk Cache, Loading Time, Network Transaction & Android

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, diskcache

First, I would like to know **"Disk Cache"** will really improve the loading time over network transaction if the network bandwidth is not a major concern ?

Why Android take too much time when I create a disk cache around 10 MB ? 
(Worse than Network Loading Time)

Is there any optimal approach to use SQLite with ORMLite to save huge data ? 'Cause My data are coming with JSONFormats, which is great for direct rendering. But, when i tried to save them on SQLite, the process got really really leggy.

I'm working on optimization of a certain network intensive & heavy program. So, I believe most of regular approach will not solve the problem.

Best Regards,